# How to calculate the input current of a 7805?

Tags: power-supply, ldo

I am using a 7805.  The drop out voltage is 2V. My load current is 470mA.  How can I calculate how much current is consumed by the linear regulator to reduce 12.7V to 5V, 470mA?

Comment: If input voltage is 12.7 V and output voltage is 5 V, the difference is 7.7 V, much more than 2 V.

Comment: You do realize that the 7805 will dissipate (12.7 - 5) * 0.47 = 3.6 Watts of heat. Have you done any thermal calculations?

Answer (score 4):

As per the topic, in a linear regulator, 470mA output current would require 470mA input current in ideal case.

In non-ideal case, add the current consumed by the regulator itself to the input current, it will vary depending on the exact model, but it should be approximately 5 to 10 mA.

Comment: Iin=Io+Iq is it correct

Comment: @amrutaBankar It is correct, but Iq can change with load current and temperature, so be sure to check the datasheet to see what it is for your operating conditions.

Comment: @JohnD Based on few datasheets, it will only vary in the order of 2 mA, over full input voltage, output current, and temperature, so not much. But if it is in the order of 5 to 10mA due to manufacturing tolerances, that 2mA is relatively high amount.

Comment: @Justme Right, and the Iq may not even be significant to the OP, but we can't tell from the question so all we can do is point it out and let the OP decide.

Answer (score 3):

> *How can I calculate how much current is consumed by the linear
> regulator*

For the [μA7805](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LM7805.pdf) the current consumed by the device (not load current) can be calculated from this: -

[image]

For the [LM7805](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf?ts=1658847359511&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) it can be found here: -

[image]